# SSAS tabular model - processing history

Tags: ssas-tabular, xmla

I'm looking for a clever solution to store information about the tabular model model processing history. I tried to use extended events tracking for that but don't know how to find a model name in that logs.

Any ideas would be really helpful.

Thx in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You can query the `$SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_CUBES` DMV and check the `LAST_DATA_UPATE` column to find when the Tabular model was last processed.  This only returns the results for the model that you're in so filtering the model isn't necessary.  If you're looking to use XMLA, you execute the example request below as an XMLA query in SSMS.  Like querying the prior mentioned DMV directly, this will run in the context of the model your connected to.

```
<Discover xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
    <RequestType>MDSCHEMA_CUBES</RequestType>
    <Restrictions />
    <Properties>
        <PropertyList>
            <Catalog>YourTabularModelName</Catalog>
        </PropertyList>
    </Properties>
</Discover>
```